# The unit ball of $l^{1}$ is closed and has empty interior in $l^{2}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know the definitions:

We say the sequence $(a_{n})$ belongs to $l^p$ if 
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^p\right)^{\frac 1p}<\infty. $$

So, the unit ball of $l^1$, and I will denote this by $B_{1},$ is the set of all sequences $(a_n)$ satisfying $$  \sum_n |a_ n|\leq1.$$

To prove that $B_1$ has empty interior I think I need use the Baire's theorem, for $l^p$ is complete. So, how can I write $B_1=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$, with $int\,A_n=\emptyset$?

Comment: First, it should be $\sum_n{|a_n|}$. Second, what you describe (with equality) is normally called the unit *sphere*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere; the unit ball would be $\sum_n{|a_n|} \le 1$.
For the problem, I'd say a very direct approach to "find a $l^1$ near sequence with a norm $\neq 1$" seems much easier.

Comment: Well, as you can see from the answer below, you should have edited your question to use sphere and keep the "=", instead of of keeping ball and editing your equality to inequality. As it stands now, using the usual definition of a (closed) unit ball, it of course has an interior (all the sequences with norm < 1).

Comment: Kavi's answer  is a good place to look.  The useful facts to be proved are: the unit ball $B_1$ of $l^1$ is closed in $l^2$ in the the $l^2$ topology, and has empty interior in $l^2$ in the $l^2$ topology.  For the second one, you can indeed use the Baire category theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer the question in the title which says that the unit ball of $\ell ^{1}$ has no interior in $\ell ^{2}$. Suppose $(a_n)$ is an interior point. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\sum |b_n-a_n|^{2} <\epsilon$ implies $\sum |b_n| \leq 1$. Choose $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{2}} <\epsilon$ an d $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac 1 n >1+\sum |a_n|$. Let $b_n=a_n+\frac 1 n$ for $n \geq N$ and $b_n=a_n$ for $n <N$. Note that $\sum |b_n-a_n|^{2} <\epsilon$ but $\sum |b_n| \geq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac 1 n -\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |a_n|>1 $. So we have a contradiction.